# react-native-elements slider is laggy

Tags: react-native, expo, victory-charts, react-native-elements, react-native-svg

The problem is that when I just use a slider only with no other code in the application only just implementing the slider then there is no problem in the slider. But when I use the slider along with the other component i.e there is lot of state variable and component on the screen then the slider is laggy and the state value change is reflecting on screen very late.

I also uses debounce from the lodash but I did'nt work , while it fixes the lag issue to some extent but since I have to update the state in real time and show it on the screen the change in the value reflecting on screen is taking time.

Please someone tell how to fix this issue.
The Below code 
**HomeScreen.js** is creating problem.
**This below code  is creating the issue and the slider is laggy and the state value is not changing instantaneously i.e. it reflect the change in the slider value lately on the screen I think is due to VictoryChart component**

To see more detail with Gif what is problem [click here](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/1924)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {View,StyleSheet,Text,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { Slider} from 'react-native-elements';
import {VictoryArea,VictoryChart,createContainer,VictoryTheme, VictoryTooltip,VictoryBar} from 'victory-native';
import {Defs,LinearGradient,Stop} from 'react-native-svg';
sampleData=[
  { key:'1',x: 'Jan', y: 5.5, c0: 2,date:'18 Jan 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'2',x: 'Feb', y: 3, c0: 1.5, date:'08 Feb 2019',bank:'Bank Of Baroda',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'3',x: 'March', y: 5, c0: 2 ,date:'19 March 2019',bank:'State Bank of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'4',x: 'Apr', y: 4, c0: 1 ,date:'18 Apr 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'5',x: 'May', y: 6, c0: 2 ,date:'15 May 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'6',x: 'June', y: 2, c0: 4 ,date:'11 June 2019',bank:'Canara Bank',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'7',x: 'July', y: 3, c0: 1 ,date:'28 July 2019',bank:'Punjab National Bank',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
]
export default class HomeScreen extends Component{
    static navigationOptions = {
        title:'Annual Employee’s Contribution',
    }
    state = {
        search: '',
        slider:0,
        age:'0',
        value:0,
        overrideSlider:true
      };
    sliderChanger =(slider) =>{
      this.setState({slider})
    }
    render(){
        const VictoryZoomVoronoiContainer = createContainer( "voronoi","cursor");
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container} >
                <ScrollView >
                  <Slider
                    value={this.state.slider}
                    onValueChange={value => {this.sliderChanger(value) }}
                    maximumValue={100}
                    step={1}
                 />
                <Text>Value: {this.state.slider}</Text>
                <View>
              <VictoryChart
                domain={{ y: [0, 7] }}
                theme={VictoryTheme.material}
                containerComponent={
                <VictoryZoomVoronoiContainer
                  labels={(d) => `${d.x}, ${d.y}`}
                  labelComponent={
                  <VictoryTooltip
                      cornerRadius={(d) => d.x > 6 ? 0 : 20}
                      pointerLength={(d) => d.y > 0 ? 5 : 20}
                      flyoutStyle={{
                      stroke: (d) => d.x === 10 ?
                          "tomato" : "black"
                      }}/>}
                  />
                  }
              >
                <Defs>
                  <LinearGradient id="gradientStroke"
                  x1="0%"
                  x2="0%"
                  y1="0%"
                  y2="100%"
                  >
                  <Stop offset="10%" stopColor="#008aefcb" stopOpacity="1" />
                  <Stop offset="100%" stopColor="#52da9c" stopOpacity="0" />
                  </LinearGradient>
                </Defs>
                <VictoryArea
                    data={sampleData}
                    interpolation="cardinal"
                    style={{
                    data: {
                        fill: 'url(#gradientStroke)',
                        stroke: '#1E93FA',
                        strokeWidth: 2
                    }
                    }}
                />
                </VictoryChart>
                </View> 
              </ScrollView>
          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Now when removing the VictoryChart slider is working properly**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {View,StyleSheet,Text,ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { Slider} from 'react-native-elements';
import {VictoryArea,VictoryChart,createContainer,VictoryTheme, VictoryTooltip,VictoryBar} from 'victory-native';
import {Defs,LinearGradient,Stop} from 'react-native-svg';
sampleData=[
  { key:'1',x: 'Jan', y: 5.5, c0: 2,date:'18 Jan 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'2',x: 'Feb', y: 3, c0: 1.5, date:'08 Feb 2019',bank:'Bank Of Baroda',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'3',x: 'March', y: 5, c0: 2 ,date:'19 March 2019',bank:'State Bank of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'4',x: 'Apr', y: 4, c0: 1 ,date:'18 Apr 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'5',x: 'May', y: 6, c0: 2 ,date:'15 May 2019',bank:'Bank Of India',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'6',x: 'June', y: 2, c0: 4 ,date:'11 June 2019',bank:'Canara Bank',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
  { key:'7',x: 'July', y: 3, c0: 1 ,date:'28 July 2019',bank:'Punjab National Bank',txid:'76jhdg74rh4h848r58'},
]
export default class HomeScreen extends Component{

    static navigationOptions = {
        title:'Annual Employee’s Contribution',
    }
    state = {
        search: '',
        slider:0,
        age:'0',
        value:0,
        overrideSlider:true
      };
    sliderChanger =(slider) =>{
      this.setState({slider})
    }
    render(){
        const VictoryZoomVoronoiContainer = createContainer( "voronoi","cursor");
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container} >
                <ScrollView >
                  <Slider
                    value={this.state.slider}
                    onValueChange={value => {this.sliderChanger(value) }}
                    maximumValue={100}
                    step={1}
                 />
                <Text>Value: {this.state.slider}</Text>
                <View>

                </View> 
              </ScrollView>
          </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
    backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8',
    flex:1
},
})
```

Comment: To see more detailed view click here...[link](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/1924)